# find discontinuity in data using awk

Tags: bash, sed, awk

Using awk, how to find out the discontinuity in series of data.
I have got data like below.

Example:
Input data:

```
shotline   shot
1001       1001
1001       1002
1001       1003
1001       1005
1001       1006
1001       1009
1002       1001
1002       1003
```

Data should be:

Missing data points:

```
1001     1004
1001     1007
1001     1008
1002     1002
```

Comment: Could you describe how a discontinuity is defined in this case? What is shotline and shot? Are the numbers paired?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working solution:

```
cat data | awk '{shotline = $1; if(shotline != last_shotline){last_shotline = shotline; last_shot = 1000;} shot = $2; while(shot != last_shot+1){ last_shot = last_shot+1; print shotline " " last_shot }; last_shot = shot;}'
```